# error: type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio & I have a problem in parsing JSON.
Here is my JSON:

```
[{
        id: 304,
        Title: "Anna and the Apocalypse",
        Year: "2017",
        Released: "30 Nov 2018",
        Runtime: "93 min",
        Genre: "Comedy, Fantasy, Horror, Musical",
        Director: "John McPhail",
        Writer: "Alan McDonald, Ryan McHenry",
        Actors: "Ella Hunt, Malcolm Cumming, Sarah Swire, Christopher Leveaux",
        Language: "English",
        Country: "UK",
        Awards: "1 nomination.",
        PosterLow: "http://movie30t.co/wp-content/themes/m30t/timthumb.php?src=http://movie30t.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Anna-and-the-Apocalypse-2017.jpg&h=200%&w=133&zc=0",
        PosterHigh: "http://movie30t.co/wp-content/themes/m30t/timthumb.php?src=http://movie30t.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Anna-and-the-Apocalypse-2017.jpg&h=700%&w=500%&zc=0",
        IMDBScore: "6.2",
        Production: "Orion Pictures",
        DL720pLink: "http://dl2.hostgig.ir/dl/f/Anna%20and%20the%20Apocalypse%202018/Anna%20and%20the%20Apocalypse%202018%20720p%20BRRip%20MOVIE30T.CO.mkv",
        DL1080pLink: "N/A",
        SubtitleLink: "N/A",
        DLDubLink: "N/A",
        State: "True",
        Status: "Active",
        ViewCount: "157",
        VoteLike: "0",
        VoteDisslike: "0",
        TrailerLink: "http://dl2.hostgig.ir/dl/t/f/Anna and the Apocalypse 2018/Anna and the Apocalypse 2018.mp4",
        Response: true,
        Type: "Movie"
      }]
```

I try to parse it like this:

```
RequestQueue queue = new Volley().newRequestQueue(this);
        final JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        MovieModel movieModel = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), MovieModel.class);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

I get the following error:

> type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

I know that I need to use `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest` but I don't know how to get the objects then?
I have searched some other posts but I didn't understand!

Can you please help me learn this?

Comment: Because the JSON you're trying to parse isn't a JSONObject but a JSONArray, if you want to parse a JSONObject, try removing the "[" "]" at the start and at the end of the JSON

Comment: @vc73 I get this Json from API , I cannot access it!

Comment: in that case, try parsing a JSONArray instead

Comment: Any reason you're using gson? Could simply parse this with JSONArray/JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    RequestQueue queue = new Volley().newRequestQueue(this);
            final JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener< JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Gson gson = new Gson();

List<MovieModel> movieModels = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), List.class);
MovieModel movieModal = movieModels.get(0);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting a `response` as a `JSONArray`.

So, you can Call

```
JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(0);
```

inside `onResponse` parse your response.

```
JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(0);
String title= jresponse.getString("Title");
Log.d("title", title);
```

I hope this will help you.